# Prove the definition of Riemann Integration for Step Functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, step-function

$f$ is RI on $[a,b]$ iff $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists h_1,h_2$ (two step functions) s.t.

$h_1 \leq f \leq h_2$ and s.t.

$$\int_{a}^{b} (h_2(x) - h_1(x)) dx \leq \epsilon$$

I am thinking if I break the integral,

$\int_{a}^{b} h_2(x)dx - \int_{a}^{b}  h_1(x) dx \leq \epsilon$

And then somehow get both of these to correspond to $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$, I'd have the result. how to get there though, I'm not quite sure. I need to somehow make these step functions into regular functions to use the definitions I know. Does anyone have any advice on how to do this one?

Comment: I think you can then form some inequalities by rewriting your integrals as sums (with appropriate partitions). Then take a refinement of the two partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any partition $P:a < x_0< x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b$, define  $M_j = \sup \{f(x) \, | \, x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]\}$ and  $m_j = \inf \{f(x) \, | \, x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]\}$, and the step functions

$$h_1(x) = \begin{cases}\sum_{j=1}^n m_j \mathbf{1}_{[x_{j-1},x_j)}(x), & a \leqslant x < b\\f(b), &x = b\end{cases}\\ h_2(x) = \begin{cases}\sum_{j=1}^n M_j \mathbf{1}_{[x_{j-1},x_j)}(x), & a \leqslant x < b\\f(b), &x = b\end{cases}$$

We have $h_1(x) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant h_2(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and

$$\int_a^b(h_2(x) - h_1(x)) \, dx = \sum_{j=1}^nM_j(x_j- x_{j-1}) - \sum_{j=1}^nm_j(x_j- x_{j-1}) = U(P,f) - L(P,f)$$

If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a partition $P$ such that the difference between the upper and lower Darboux sums is less than $\epsilon$, that is $U(P,f) - L(P,f)< \epsilon$, which proves the forward implication.

For the reverse implication, step functions are integrable (although this is already assumed in the statement).

Since, $h_1 \leqslant f \leqslant h_2$, we have

$$ \inf \{h_1(x) \, | \, x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]\}\leqslant m_j \leqslant M_j \leqslant  \sup \{h_2(x) \, | \, x \in [x_{j-1},x_j]\},$$

and

$$L(P, h_1) \leqslant L(P,f) \leqslant U(P,f) \leqslant U(P,h_2)$$

Thus,

$$\int_a^b h_1(x)\, dx =\sup_PL(P,h_1)\leqslant \sup_PL(P,f) = \underline{\int_a}^bf(x) \, dx \\\leqslant \overline{\int_a^b}f(x) \, dx = \inf_PU(P,f) \leqslant \inf U(P,h_2)=\int_a^bh_2(x) \, dx  $$

Hence, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist step functions $h_1$ and $h_2$ such that

$$0 \leqslant \overline{\int_a^b}f(x) \, dx - \underline{\int_a}^bf(x) \, dx\leqslant \int_a^b(h_2(x)-h_1(x)) \, dx \leqslant \epsilon,$$

and the upper an lower Darboux integrals of $f$ must be equal, proving the reverse implication that $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Wow. I'm going to need some time to digest this, but it looks good from my brief glance at it. If I have any questions I'll let you know. I don't have time to fully look at it right now, but I wanted to let you know it looks good!

Comment: I do have a few questions after looking at it now. How do you get from the long inequality to the last step? The integral of $h_1(x)$ is less than the lower integral of f(x). However, what if $h_1(x)$ is significantly smaller? I don't see why the integral $h_2(x) - h_1(x)$ is necessarily greater than the upper and lower subtraction of f(x). Also, how do you get the $\epsilon$ from that? I will say, my class did not cover Darboux integrals. This is my first time hearing that term. So maybe it is just my lack of knowledge that is hurting me here. Can you explain that last step a bit more?

Comment: @DominicBlanco: Let me answer those questions one at a time and make sure you understand.  First, the the long inequality is of the form $A \leqslant B \leqslant C \leqslant D$, so $C-B \leqslant D-B$.  Since $B \geqslant A$, we have $-B \leqslant -A$ and $D-B = D+(-B) \leqslant D+(-A) = D-A$. Thus $C-B \leqslant D-A$.

Comment: Now you have $0 \leqslant \overline{\int_a^b}f(x) \, dx - \underline{\int_a}^bf(x) \, dx\leqslant \int_a^bh_2(x) \, dx - \int_a^bh_1(x) \, dx$.

Comment: Got it. I see it now. Thank you for explaining! So I do see how the proof finishes now. I do want to understand more of the context though, if you don't mind. The integrals with the lines above and below you mention are the upper and lower Darboux integrals. I have not worked with those before. Can you explain what those are specifically? That way I fully understand all of the context. Thanks!

Comment: Upper and lower Darboux sums are defined for some partition $P = (x_0,x_1,\ldots, x_n$ as $U(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n M_j(x_j- x_{j-1})$ and $L(P,f) = \sum_{j=1}^n m_j(x_j- x_{j-1})$ where $M_j$ and $m_j$ are the sup and inf of $f$ over the subinterval $[x_{j-1},x_j]$.  You can show that if $P$ and $Q$ are any partitions, then  $L(P,f) \leqslant U(Q,f)$. So when $f$ is bounded, the set $\{L(P,f)\}$ is bounded above and  the set $\{U(P,f)\}$ is bounded below.  The upper and lower Darboux integrals always exist and are given by $\underline{\int_a}^bf = \sup_PL(P,f)$ and ...

Comment: ... $\overline{\int_a^b}f = \inf_PU(P,f)$. We always have $ \underline{\int_a}^bf \leqslant \overline{\int_a^b}f$.  The function $f$ is Riemann integrable iff  $\underline{\int_a}^b f = \overline{\int_a^b} f$ and the integral $\int_a^b f$ is equal to both the upper and lower integrals.

Comment: In my inequality I immediately wrote $\int_a^b h_1$ on the left since it is given that $h_1$ is integrable and I knew that $\underline{\int_a}^b h_1 = \int_a^b h_1$. Similarly for $\int_a^b h_2$ on the right.

Comment: Ah. We called those expressions (Inf_P U(f,P) and Sup_P L(f,P)) U(f) and L(f) respectively. We just didn't write them as integrals. That makes sense now. Thank you!